# Solving Shift/Reduce

Tags: bison, yacc

So I've been trying to create a somewhat simple compiler.

At the moment I'm having 2 shift/reduce conflicts that I can't really figure out how to solve.

I have this so far:

(DECR and INCR is basically -- and ++, and ID is basically an identifier)

```
%token INCR DECR ID
%nonassoc INCR DECR
%%
lvalue: ID
      | lvalue '[' rvalue ']'
      ;
rvalue: lvalue               (49)
      | lvalue INCR          
      | lvalue DECR
      | INCR lvalue          (95)
      | DECR lvalue          (96)
```

And I'm getting the problem there.

```
67: shift/reduce conflict (shift 95, reduce 49) on INCR
67: shift/reduce conflict (shift 96, reduce 49) on DECR
```

Comment: Evidently that is not your entire grammar. That snippet does not have any parse conflicts at all, so it fails to illustrate the problem you are having. Please provide a complete grammar (not necessarily your entire grammar, but one which can be processed with bison without errors) which does show the conflicts.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/AWDd2WtN thats a pastebin with the output after compiling. I thought the problem was from only the part I posted, and dind't think it would come from somewhere else.

Comment: That pastebin doesn't show a conflict, either.

Comment: If you scroll to the end there says 2 conflicts on state 67

Comment: Byacc and no that's the original file

Comment: Really, it would be more useful to have your grammar. In that listing, I can't see your precedence declarations, for example. And anyway, SO discourages answering questions based on information which is not in the question, because that's not very useful to future readers.

Comment: Ah, byacc. Ok, that explains the weird format.

Comment: I will try to put a paste in with the grammar tomorrow if that's needed. In bed at the moment. Didn't think I would get help so fast.