# YACC Grammar fix shift-reduce error with increment/decrement

Tags: grammar, yacc, lex

I'm new to grammar's and I can't fix a shift-reduce error.

I want my language to accept expressions that are a simple ID, ID++, ID--, --ID or ID++.

I have the following definition:

```
lvalue : ID (will be extended to have more ways to address variables)
expr : lvalue
       | lvalue INCR
       | lvalue DECR
       | INCR lvalue
       | DECR lvalue
       | lvalue ATR expr
       (...)
       | expr '&' expr
       | expr '|' expr
       | '(' expr ')'
       ;
```

I have the following precedences:

```
%nonassoc INCR DECR
%left '+' '-'
%right ATR
(...)
```

For INCR lvalue and DECR lvalue I don't get any error, but YACC says it has a shift-reduce error on lvalue INCR and lvalue DECR. The output says:

```
"95: shift/reduce conflict (shift 123, reduce 57) on INCR
95: shift/reduce conflict (shift 124, reduce 57) on DECR
state 95
    expr : lvalue .  (57)
    expr : lvalue . INCR  (61)
    expr : lvalue . DECR  (62)
    expr : lvalue . ATR expr  (65)"
```

I have tried removing lvalue ATR expr but it doesn't solve the issue. Only removing expr : lvalue solves the issue, but I need the expression to be a simple ID too.

Can you help me fix this or tell me where to look?

Comment: This seems very similar to [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55554863/solving-shift-reduce). As indicated in the comment stream there, any advice requires a complete grammar because it is the result of an interaction between different rules. Please see the help section on providing a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55554863/solving-shift-reduce)?

Comment: Note: The similarity between these questions, the provided grammar, and the choice of tools leads me to suspect that both of you are taking the same course and that some or all of the code was provided for the assignment. There's nothing wrong with that (provided that seeking help here is acceptable to the school) but we do require complete code and if the code is not yours, you need to verify that publishing it is ok.

Comment: Thanks for the help, we are probably implementing the same university project. As such I can't post any code. Where would you look if you had the code?

Comment: Corrected link for the help section: [mcve]

Comment: trace the parse through the state machine. The question you need to ask yourself is "how can it get to this state?"

Comment: If you can't provide code, I'll mark this question for closure.

Answer (score 0):

The conflict indicates that you have a rule for `lvalue` that right-recursive and has no precedence -- that is a rule something like:

```
lvalue: something lvalue
```

or several rules that can combine to the same effect.  That's the rule(s) you need to look at.